# Updating Mongoose Subdocument Array By ID

Tags: mongoose, graphql, crud, subdocument, findoneandupdate

I am using GraphQL and Mongoose, and there is a subdocument within the document "Events" that will have an array of "tasks".  I want users to be able to perform standard CRUD operations on these tasks and events, and I have been able to implement create and read operations just fine, but struggling over updates.  Because the parent document is itself within an array of other events for a given user, I have been using `Event.findOneAndUpdate` to access the event whose tasks we want to edit, say to change the name.  But how can I access the particular task from among the array of other tasks to update, without setting them all?

Event model:

```
const {Schema, model} = require("mongoose");
const taskSchema = require("./Task");
const dateFormat = require("../utils/dateFormat");

const eventSchema = new Schema(
    {
        eventName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        eventType: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        eventDate: {
            required: true,
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            get: dueDate => dateFormat(dueDate)
        },
        duration: {
            type: Number,
            min: 0.25,
            max: 12,
            required: false
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        tasks: [taskSchema]
    },
    {
        toJSON: {
            getters: true
        }
    }
);

eventSchema.virtual("taskCount").get(function() {
    return this.tasks.length;
});

const Event = model("Event", eventSchema);

module.exports = Event;
```

(unfinished) Edit Task resolver:

```
editTask: async (parent, {eventID, taskID, name, dueDate, completed}) => {
    const updatedEvent = await Event.findOneAndUpdate(
        {tasks._id: taskID},
        {
            $set: {
                tasks.$.name: name,

            }
        }
    );

    };

    return updatedEvent;

}
```

The Mutation as it appears in my Apollo sandbox:

```
export const EDIT_TASK = gql`
mutation editTask($eventID: ID!, $taskID: ID!, $name: String, $dueDate: String, $completed: String){
    editTask(eventID: $eventID, taskID: $taskID, name: $name, dueDate: $dueDate, completed: $completed) {
        _id
        eventName
        tasks {
            _id
            name
            dueDate
            completed
        }
    }
}
`
```

I would love to figure out how I can specifically select the task I want to update, and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track right now.  Thanks!